# Solar charging in northern urban environment - boost mode needed?

Tags: battery-charging, solar-cell, solar-charge-controller

I have a metrology device I need to sustain off 12V LiFePO4 batteries in a northern climate (near latitude 43.65) and urban environment. Solar panels will be 50W 24Voc (~18V maximum power point) with a load of about 1W. The summertime is not a concern but during winter with low angle of sun and high-rise buildings all around, reflected/indirect light will be about all the panel will get.

A few designs I've reviewed talk about efficiency at high charge rates. I don't think I care much about direct sun efficiency, whereas squeezing out performance in low light is valuable.

Is there anything one should do differently designing a charger optimized for such an environment compared to a general purpose solar charger? Does having a boost stage help matters much?

Comment: It looks like you just need a quite bigger solar panel capable of providing necessary charge under your solar-depressed environment. Nit-picking on efficiency would not solve your problem.

Comment: Look up terms like `energy harvesting` with `solar`. Be aware that Texas Instruments is working with partners to create appropriate battery storage (which is kind of a bridge between capacitors and the usual re-chargeable battery technology), as well. A system design to get the most out of what you have available will involve ***every*** facet: energy storage tech, solar panel tech, MCU specification and design, and software design. You may need to extract all available energy from the panels even when the voltage is quite low and that can be a challenge all its own.

Comment: "northern"? Australia or Canada? Give latitude!

Comment: @Transistor added latitude info

Comment: The voltage of the maximum power point doesn't vary a lot with illumination. It varies more with temperature: hot is yields low voltage, cold yields high. You need a complete spec on the panels to decide if a boost will be useful.

Answer (score 3):

The maximum power point of a solar cell depends on the amount of light it receives (called "insolation", which is neither a typo for "isolation" nor for "insulation"). The 18V MPP you quote is only valid at "datasheet conditions", likely 1000W/m² insolation, which you are likely never getting in a region you would call "northern". The lower the insolation, the lower the power at the voltage-dependent MPP (obviously), but a lower insolation also means a lower voltage of the MPP.

Better solar charge controllers contain an "MPP tracker". Those controllers use a voltage converter to convert from the MPP voltage at the current insolation to the required output voltage. If you care about efficiency at sub-par lighting conditions, you should use a charge controller like that, as in any case in which the MPP voltage is lower than the required charge voltage (for a 4-cell LiFePo, you need around 14.5V), the resulting charge current will be very low without boosting the voltage.

A charge controller with MPP tracker will also be able to run in buck mode if the MPP voltage is higher than the required output voltage, providing even more current than a direct connection between the panel and the solar cell would provide, but in those conditions you likely already have enough power at 14.5V to 15V output, so the buck mode of the MPP tracker isn't as important to you as the boost mode.

In a very coarse approximation, at voltages below the MPP, the power delivered to the load drops linearly with the voltage, so in data-sheet like ideal lighting conditions, you would expect 25W to 30W at half the output voltage (9V), and around 40W at 14.5W, likely even slightly higher. On the other hand, above the MPP the available power will plummet quickly until it reaches zero at the open circuit voltage.

If the size of the panels is not an issue, but low-light performance is an issue, your other option would be to design the system with a considerably higher open circuit voltage, so you will still have enough voltage at lower lighting conditions, even with a "classic charge controller" wihout boost converter. Oversizing the panels is likely more expensive than getting a charge controller with MPP tracking, so this approach is likely not the right one for you.

Answer (score 1):

The most important is to reduce power consumption of your load as much as possible. "About 1W" sounds like a wet-finger-in-the-wind estimation. In this scenario where you need to guarantee power will be available at all times, every fraction of a watt costs a lot of money because it translates directly into battery capacity and solar panel area.

**Matching panel and battery voltages**

Your charge controller (preferably MPPT) can either use a buck, boost, or buck-boost converter, the latter being the more complicated option. If you pick a buck converter, it can only lower voltage, and some have restrictions  on output/input voltage ratio due to duty cycle limitation. If you pick a boost, it can only increase voltage. So you have to make sure the converter can operate at the panel's  MPP voltage especially in low light.

12V LiFePo4 battery goes from 10V when discharged to 14.6V when fully charged.

The panel's MPP voltage, indicated by the jagged diagonal line, drops quite a lot at low illumination ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_power_point_tracking)):

[image]

My point is you need to map the panel's MPP voltage in the illumination conditions you expect, versus battery voltage, versus the input/output voltage range of the DC-DC converter, and make sure it all aligns properly.

With the panel and battery you're quoting, you'll need a buck-boost converter to get good efficiency at high and low illumination ; using a boost only means lower efficiency at high illumination. You could keep it this way, or use a panel with higher voltage and a buck converter.

**Efficiency**

> I don't think I care much about direct sun efficiency

It depends. On some days the weather will be so bad production will be negligible. Or the panel may be covered with snow until it melts or someone wipes is off. So you will need a big enough battery to run the device for maybe a week (check local weather conditions). Then there's a cloudy day but you still get one hour of direct sunlight: in this case you'll want to make the most of it. So I'd say you can sacrifice high power efficiency, but not the capability to exploit peaks. Here's a cloudy day on my PV, for example.

[image]

**Idle power**

In your case, after matching voltages, the most important thing is likely to be the current draw of the MPP charge controller at idle and at low power. It should be as low as possible, and near zero at night.

For example let's look at this [Victron charge controller](https://www.victronenergy.com/upload/documents/Datasheet-SmartSolar-charge-controller-MPPT-75-10,-75-15,-100-15,-100-20_48V-EN.pdf). It boasts "98% efficiency", great! But it uses 230mW just to idle, even at night, which means it's not suitable.

This means the charger has to turn itself off at night, and during the day it should use power-saving modes like skipping cycles or going to sleep periodically. A way to do this is to have a capacitor in parallel with the panel which accumulates energy, and only activate the DC-DC in bursts while letting it sleep most of the time. This complicates the MPPT algorithm. When the panel is covered in snow, it will still produce voltage but almost no power, so it should be smart enough to give up instead of staying powered and draining the battery.

You should also check what temperatures your battery can tolerate, especially for charging.

Comment: 1W is after a lot of optimizations such as sleeping host between reporting intervals. "about" because there are triggered events and cellular TxRx depends on frequency of triggers. I'd love to have an hour of direct light a day, these often end up in alleyways between buildings which only get direct light in summer. Why there's no AC supply is political and out of my scope.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there anything one should do differently designing a charger optimized for such an environment compared to a general purpose solar charger?

Yes.  Unless you have a mad desire to charge those batteries faster than fast on sunny summer days, you probably want to design the charger around the assumption that it'll be hugely efficient on a cloudy winter day, and just allow a restriction on maximum charging rate to happen.

I.e., if you **need** to charge at 1W at your lowest expected "reasonable" lighting conditions, then you probably **don't** need to charge at more than 2 or 3 watts, ever.  So you can design the system to be super-efficient on those dreary winter days, and to just not bother to take advantage of more than a fraction of the available power in the summer.

> Does having a boost stage help matters much?

Only if the maximum power point of the panel **in your worst lighting conditions** is less than the fully-charged voltage of your battery pack.  If it's less -- you need boost.  If it's more -- you don't need boost.  If you're designing the whole system, you may want to price out a solar panel that meets this criteria, rather than designing in an extra, possibly inefficient, stage.  Or not -- price out both, and make your decision.

Comment: Thanks, if I spec a panel that sits well above Vbat in cloudy conditions I imagine it will exceed many charger's max Vin during direct light so that translates into specing a charger with a high Vin range. I wonder how the design complexity and material cost of that generally compares to buck-boost.

Comment: You were asking about _designing_ a charger.  Now you sound like you're _choosing_ a charger.  Either way -- system design is all about trading off one thing for another, and finding the best solution for your particular circumstance.

Comment: designing a charger, but that (potentially) involves choosing an IC (e.g. LTC3652) and those have a range of Vin they can accept.